# How to debug program creating RAW socket?

Tags: linux, sudo, c++, c, sockets

For example I have this program:

```
int main()
{
  int sockfd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);

  if ( sockfd == -1 )
    printf("Error\n");
  else
    printf("Success\n");

  return 0;
```

}

So, I need to have super user's rights or to use `setcap`:

```
$ ./Test 
Error
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+eip ./Test
$ ./Test 
Success
```

But, I need to debug my program with QtCretor and the program doesn't work even after `setcap`. I have tried to apply `setcap` to QtCreator, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Are there any solutions?